# access particular json data in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have json structure like this:

```
{
  "states": [
 {
  "images": {
    "small": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34s/88221849.png",
    "medium": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64s/88221849.png",
    "large": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/88221849.png",
    "extralarge": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/300x300/88221849.png"
  },
  "capital": "Amravathi",
  "name": "Andhra Pradesh"
},
{
  "images": {
    "small": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34s/96506699.png",
    "medium": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64s/96506699.png",
    "large": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/96506699.png",
    "extralarge": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/300x300/96506699.png"
  },
  "capital": "Itanagar",
  "name": "Arunachal Pradesh"
},
```

I want to return that json using angularjs factory method using promise. I have two empty object states{} and capitals{}. When i use

```
(function(promise) { return [promise[0].data.states,   promise[0].data.states.capital]; })
    .subscribe(function(result) {
        $scope.states = result[0].slice(0, 5);
        $scope.capitals = result[1].slice(0, 5);
```

states object are getting all values but capital object is empty. I want to access only capital option from that json and store it in capital object. how can i do that, give me some suggestion please.

Comment: `capital` is not an array, so why do you call `slice`?

Comment: I am working on angularjs typeahead and when user type something in input, it display 5 suggestion from states and 5 suggestion from capital.

Comment: Maybe your JSON example is incomplete. Maybe there is a `capitals` property, but then it would have to be `promise[0].data.capitals`.

Comment: yes there is two different json file but i want to use only one thats why i combined two json file into one. can you suggest me how can i access that capital by using only one json file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), like this:

```
(function(promise) { return [promise[0].data.states, promise[0].data.states.capital]; })
    .subscribe(function(result) {
        $scope.states = result[0].slice(0, 5);

        // .map() runs a function for every item in an array and
        // creates a new array from whatever values the function returns:
        $scope.capitals = $scope.states.map(
            function( item ){ 
                return item.capital;
            }
        );
```